# The QRsolve method of sympy never returns or throws "Could not normalize the vector" error

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I've tried QRsolve and cholesky_solve on the matrices shown below (printed str repr). I get results from numpy with these. The functions never return with sympy, I guess this has something to do with sympy trying to solve these using a symbolic method? The reason I'm trying sympy is that as my system becomes more complex the matrices become ill-conditioned and I am attempting to increase the precision using sympy and mpmath.

```
from sympy.matrices import Matrix as sy_matrix

A = sy_matrix([[-1.73598602689344 - 0.555723094599341j, -1.73598602689344 - 0.555723094599341j, 0.232989179693563 - 0.308565151130628j, 0.232989179693563 - 0.308565151130628j, 0.785911137306334 + 0.373372141423308j, 0.785911137306334 + 0.373372141423308j, 0.436377021604638 + 0.329496457808818j, 0.436377021604638 + 0.329496457808818j],
[-2.47182252542744 - 3.12228363243637j, -8.23364083219883 - 10.4003267796456j, 0.752244101320904 + 0.206999511678148j, 2.50572510149994 + 0.689515373399912j, 8.05887958417013 + 10.8152044077855j, 26.8441278948708 + 36.0254458823337j, -0.534283343532919 + 1.94160599872119j, -1.77969781730816 + 6.46748958174029j],
[-2.44359008697499 - 4.49072303037516j, -13.8356070724522 - 25.4264737979839j, 1.0065385313486 + 0.721365705527217j, 5.69902116449569 + 4.08437262469506j, 15.1118001221454 + 29.8836019724734j, 85.5630122915864 + 169.200954368143j, -2.42747866727978 + 3.38711806497384j, -13.744384214138 + 19.1778624838817j],
[-3.12331363856586 - 6.06170033660146j, -24.9646459130564 - 48.4511707904544j, 1.44382306453606 + 1.1598998787916j, 11.5404777548365 + 9.27107973118107j, 24.2361910493061 + 51.4282308184496j, 193.719875057099 + 411.065848931859j, -4.63756924615993 + 5.77276501482576j, -37.0680909845555 + 46.1417107635014j],
[0.232989179693563 - 0.308565151130628j, 0.232989179693563 - 0.308565151130628j, -1.73598602689344 - 0.555723094599341j, -1.73598602689344 - 0.555723094599341j, 0.436377021604638 + 0.329496457808818j, 0.436377021604638 + 0.329496457808818j, 0.785911137306335 + 0.373372141423309j, 0.785911137306335 + 0.373372141423309j],
[0.752244101320904 + 0.206999511678148j, 2.50572510149994 + 0.689515373399912j, -2.47182252542744 - 3.12228363243637j, -8.23364083219883 - 10.4003267796456j, -0.534283343532919 + 1.94160599872119j, -1.77969781730816 + 6.46748958174029j, 8.05887958417013 + 10.8152044077855j, 26.8441278948708 + 36.0254458823337j],
[1.0065385313486 + 0.721365705527217j, 5.69902116449569 + 4.08437262469506j, -2.44359008697499 - 4.49072303037516j, -13.8356070724522 - 25.4264737979839j, -2.42747866727978 + 3.38711806497384j, -13.744384214138 + 19.1778624838817j, 15.1118001221454 + 29.8836019724734j, 85.5630122915864 + 169.200954368143j],
[1.44382306453606 + 1.1598998787916j, 11.5404777548365 + 9.27107973118107j, -3.12331363856586 - 6.06170033660146j, -24.9646459130564 - 48.4511707904544j, -4.63756924615993 + 5.77276501482576j, -37.0680909845555 + 46.1417107635014j, 24.2361910493061 + 51.4282308184496j, 193.7198750571 + 411.065848931859j]])

b = sy_matrix([[1.73598602689344 + 0.555723094599341j], [0.742066203971011 + 0.937341228590923j], [0.431577196569235 + 0.793133703704558j], [0.39075611642261 + 0.758376121181231j], [-0.232989179693563 + 0.308565151130628j], [-0.225831312314891 - 0.06214335385114j], [-0.177770846229001 - 0.127404751947585j], [-0.180635939514086 - 0.145114460001454j]])

x = A.QRsolve(b)
```

I pasted the code as suggested in the comment, constructing a simple repo script. The difference here is that I create the matrices on initialisation, rather than value-by-value. Now I don't get a block but the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sympyTest.py", line 14, in 
    x = A.QRsolve(b)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 1633, in QRsolve
    Q, R = self.as_mutable().QRdecomposition()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\matrices\matrices.py", line 1599, in QRdecomposition
    "Could not normalize the vector %d." % j)
NotImplementedError: Could not normalize the vector 1.

Comment: Probability to get an answer may be higher if you provide code which we can copy and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [QRsolve documentation says](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.QRsolve),

> This is mainly for educational purposes and symbolic matrices, for real (or complex) matrices use sympy.mpmath.qr_solve.

I suggest following this advice, or just use mpmath on its own.

Here is a much simpler repro of the issue qith QRsolve:

```
A = sy_matrix([[2+3j, 1], [1, 1]])
b = sy_matrix([[1], [1]])
A.QRsolve(b)
```

This throws "NotImplementedError: Could not normalize the vector 0." because the QRdecomposition method, on which QRsolve relies, does not even try to handle floating point errors. [This is what it does](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/matrices/matrices.py#L1663):

```
R[j, j] = tmp.norm()
Q[:, j] = tmp / R[j, j]
if Q[:, j].norm() != 1:
    raise NotImplementedError("Could not normalize the vector %d." % j)
```

Obviously, the vector obtained by dividing a column of floating-point numbers by its norm need not have norm exactly 1. In my example,

```
>>> (A[:,0]/A[:,0].norm()).norm() == 1
False
```

Comment: Thanks lots, I understand. I had tried sympy.mpmath.qr_solve and ended up having to ask the following question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810785/cannot-create-mpf-when-calling-qr-solve